# Cocos2dx - erro ao usar sdkbox pra importar plugins

Tags: cocos2dx

Estou usando o `sdkbox (v0.5.6.7)` num projeto `Cocos2dx (v3.7.1)` mas toda vez que executo a sdkbox dá o seguinte erro:

```
$> sdkbox import facebook
 _______ ______  _     _ ______   _____  _     _
 |______ |     \ |____/  |_____] |     |  \___/ 
 ______| |_____/ |    \_ |_____] |_____| _/   \_
Copyright (c) 2015 Chukong Technologies Inc. v0.5.6.7

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "monolith.py", line 4327, in <module>
  File "monolith.py", line 4312, in main
  File "monolith.py", line 3507, in perform
  File "monolith.py", line 3515, in perform
  File "monolith.py", line 3979, in main
  File "monolith.py", line 3507, in perform
  File "monolith.py", line 3515, in perform
  File "monolith.py", line 4195, in cmd_import
  File "monolith.py", line 3949, in load_projects
  File "monolith.py", line 3666, in load_xcode_project
  File "monolith.py", line 2161, in initialize
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in     _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado
```

Esse mesmo erro aconteceu enquanto testava a `sdkbox` com a versão `3.6` do `cocos2dx`, daí atualizei porque pensei ser um erro na instalação que fiz da `sdkbox` (porque antes da 3.7 ela não vinha junto com o framework) ou alguma coisa com a versão 3.6. Depois que atualizei o erro persiste. Já perguntei pro tio google e nada.

Não mexi em nada; o que fiz foi instalar a versão 3.7.1 por meio do `setup.py`, depois criei um projeto do zero, então copiei os meus arquivos fonte que eram do outro projeto, e tentei importar o plugin, mas dá esse erro. O projeto tá beleza, constrói os executáveis tranquilo, mas não consigo usar a `sdkbox`. Alguém sabe o que está errado?